# Enviar parametros desde php y volver a recibirlos

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo el siguiente dilema (soy nuevo en esto):

Tengo un `shortcode`  en mi archivo `shortcodes.php` para una pagina en wordpress, en el cual deseo poder seleccionar una fecha desde un `datepicker`. A esta fecha quiero recibirla en un archivo llamado `historico.php` donde se van a ejecutar funciones con esta fecha que llega. 
Lo que yo quiero, es que la fecha se envie, se procese, y poder renderizar los resultados de las funciones de `historico.php` en el `shortcode` donde ingreso la fecha.

Lo que tengo:

`shortcodes.php:`

```
add_shortcode('dmp_historico','ecw_historico');
function ecw_historico($atts,$content){
ob_start();                           
?>
 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body  text-center ">
            <form method="POST" action="historico.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h2 class="card-title m-b-0d-inline">Seleccione una fecha para ver el historial</h2>
                    <input class="text-center"  type="date" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" name="fecha_historico">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </form> 
            <?php if(isset($_POST['fecha_historico'])) {
                echo '<p> La fecha elegida es '.mostrar_fecha_elegida();
            }
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`historico.php:`

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['fecha_historico'])){
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha_historico'];
}
$fechaComoEntero = strtotime($fecha);
$dia = date("d", $fechaComoEntero);
$mes = date("m", $fechaComoEntero);
$anio = date("Y", $fechaComoEntero);


function mostrar_fecha_elegida(){

    return $fecha;
}
```

Lo que yo quiero es, una vez que aprete el botón `Enviar` del formulario, ser reenviado a la misma pagina en la que estoy actualmente (que seria /dmp_historico y no /historico.php), desde donde llamaría a las funciones de `historico.php`, que estarían trabajando con esta fecha que le envió y devolviendo datos en consecuencia. No se si soy claro con la explicacion, espero hacerme entender.

**Lo que esta sucediendo:** Me redirecciona a una pagina llamada misitio.com/historico.php donde no me muestra nada (tiene sentido ya que le puse otros.php en el action, ja)

**Lo que quiero que suceda:** Que me vuelva a redireccionar a la pagina donde se encuentra el formulario, y que imprima la fecha que el usuario eligio cuando pase por el condicional:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['fecha_historico'])) {
    echo '<p> La fecha elegida es '.mostrar_fecha_elegida();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Agustin editare tu código y comentaré lo que realicé...

`shortcodes.php:`

```
add_shortcode('dmp_historico','ecw_historico');
function ecw_historico($atts,$content){
ob_start();                           
?>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body  text-center ">
        <form method="POST" action="historico.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h2 class="card-title m-b-0d-inline">Seleccione una fecha para ver el historial</h2>
                <input class="text-center"  type="date" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" name="fecha_historico">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!--Cambié el tipo de dato y el valor que recibimos-->
        <?php if(isset($_GET['val'])) {
            //aqui se imprime el valor recibido condicionado
            $value = $_GET['val'];
            if($value != "error"){
                echo '<p> La fecha elegida es '.$_GET['val']. '</p>';
            }else{
                echo "Mensaje de de error";
            }
        }
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`historico.php:`

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['fecha_historico'])){
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha_historico'];
    //He movido el proceso aqui, ya que afuera no tendría sentido trabajarlo si no recibimos el POST
    $fechaComoEntero = strtotime($fecha);
    $dia = date("d", $fechaComoEntero);
    $mes = date("m", $fechaComoEntero);
    $anio = date("Y", $fechaComoEntero);
}else{
    //esto solo sera un mensaje en caso que la fecha no es seleccionada
    $fecha = "Error";
}
//debes editar la ruta para volver a shortcodes.php
$ruta = "ruta/a/shortcodes.php";
//enviaremos el valor $fecha por GET
$return = "?val=$fecha"
header("Location: $ruta"."$return");
//Este valor no se esta retornando
//function mostrar_fecha_elegida(){
    //return $fecha;
//}
```